# Matching a 'Key' in a Dictionary from a String, and returning a 'Value'

Tags: python, string, dictionary, matching

Dear stack overflow community:

I've been trying to tackle a case where a user enters an input, which is a string, and the words within the string are compared to the 'keys' in a predefined dictionary to see if there is a match. If a match exits, to return the corresponding 'value' for the 'key' in the dictionary.

**For example:**

thisdict =  {
"limit": "daily transaction limits through online banking",
"payout": "payout loan through online banking",
}

print('Notes: ', end='')
user_input = input()

**assuming the user types the following input in the prompt:**
*client would like to increase their purchase limit*

I was thinking to tackle it by applying '.split()' to the input so that each word would be isolated.

Then, running a 'for loop' to match each word in the string to each key in the dictionary. Subsequently, returning any 'value' for the 'keys' that match the words in the string.

Thus, in the example with the input *client would like to increase their purchase limit*, it would match the word 'limit' and return *daily transaction limits through online banking*.

I've been having difficulties translating this to code in Python, and was hoping for some assistance.

Comment: could you show us what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to test whether the word is a key in the dictionary:

```
def lookup(dct, sentence):
    """
    splits the input sentence into words and returns the value from dct for
    the first word that is a key, or None if none are found.
    """
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word in dct:  # <== this tests the word against the dictionary keys
            return dct[word]  # <== do the lookup (we know the key exists)
    return None  # <== no matches were found in the 'for' loop


thisdict = { "limit": "daily transaction limits through online banking", "payout": "payout loan through online banking", }

print('Notes: ', end='')
user_input = input()

print(lookup(thisdict, user_input))
```